# Spark streaming error: Issue communicating with driver in heartbeater

Tags: scala, apache-spark, spark-streaming

I'm experimenting an issue with heartbeating when I running my Spark Streaming app.

I know the meaning of heartbeating, I have tried to increase its value in "spark.executor.heartbeatInterval", but the issue it still remaing.

My config is:

- 4 executors
- 4 cores per executor
- 6GB RAM per executor
- Spark streaming time window: 30s
- Each batch takes between 2s and 28s to complete

In the logs I can see how, suddenly, executors start to log "Issue communicating with driver in heartbeater" and when the it happen X times, the executor shutdown (as the spark doc says).

In the logs I can't see any exception (such as OOM or something about GC). Simply, some time (some hours after starting), heartbeater fails.

I have read about to repartition data to try to solve the issue, but I can't because it is a Kafka Direct appication and each partition is partial ordered so I don't do repartition anytime.

This is the trace I can see:

> 

```
2018/12/16 13:44:26:317 WARN org.apache.spark.executor.Executor: Issue communicating with driver in heartbeater
org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcTimeoutException: Futures timed out after [10 seconds]. This timeout is controlled by spark.executor.heartbeatInterval
    at org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcTimeout.org$apache$spark$rpc$RpcTimeout$$createRpcTimeoutException(RpcTimeout.scala:47)
    at org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcTimeout$$anonfun$addMessageIfTimeout$1.applyOrElse(RpcTimeout.scala:62)
    at org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcTimeout$$anonfun$addMessageIfTimeout$1.applyOrElse(RpcTimeout.scala:58)
    at scala.runtime.AbstractPartialFunction.apply(AbstractPartialFunction.scala:36)
    at org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcTimeout.awaitResult(RpcTimeout.scala:76)
    at org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcEndpointRef.askSync(RpcEndpointRef.scala:92)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor.org$apache$spark$executor$Executor$$reportHeartBeat(Executor.scala:785)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$$anon$2$$anonfun$run$1.apply$mcV$sp(Executor.scala:814)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$$anon$2$$anonfun$run$1.apply(Executor.scala:814)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$$anon$2$$anonfun$run$1.apply(Executor.scala:814)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.logUncaughtExceptions(Utils.scala:1988)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$$anon$2.run(Executor.scala:814)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:308)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$301(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:294)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: Futures timed out after [10 seconds]
    at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise.ready(Promise.scala:219)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise.result(Promise.scala:223)
    at org.apache.spark.util.ThreadUtils$.awaitResult(ThreadUtils.scala:201)
    at org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcTimeout.awaitResult(RpcTimeout.scala:75)
    ... 14 more
```

Comment: So far the problem continue. I'm restarting the job every day in order to prevent the hearbet fail but this is not a good solution.

Comment: I have found likewise that the only way to get rid of the error is to restart my terminal and even clear/invalidate cache on my application.